# Harvesting Broccoli

Tags: raised-beds, harvesting, brassicas, broccoli

I am growing some late season broccoli in my backyard in a raised bed.  How do I decide the right time to harvest the broccoli?  Are there any visual clues I can use?  I can't use the time from planting because I don't remember when I planted and given that I planted them late in the season, I think it has taken longer than normal to produce broccoli.

Answer (score 4):

Cut the floret bunch off as soon as it looks big enough. Don't wait too long as it gets pithy.  Broccoli and cauliflower are very tasty young and smallish.  If you harvest sooner they might be able to start a new head.  Smaller is tastier...